# Is it possible to store SL4A scripts in a local db and run them from within a java Activity.class?

Tags: android, python, database, sl4a

I'm toying around with an idea in which I store SL4A code script snippets inside a db local to a "regular" java Android app.  The idea is to retrieve those code snippets from within an Activity class at run time and execute them.

I haven't been able to find any examples despite my best google-fu, which strikes me as a bad sign. Plenty of examples on how to run SL4A scripts, but none that seem to show an example of how to retrieve a script as a String(or stream) object and then execute the script from within an Activity.

I did find one example that was close to what I want, but it didn't seem to offer the ability to execute multiple lines of script and it required root access.

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the script contents from your DB and then write it to a file, finally calling for SL4A to run it? An example in a made up / Python-y language:

```py
// get script
script = db.fetchScript(ID)
// write script to file
path = "/mnt/sdcard/myapp/scripts/temp.py"
file = open(path,Mode.WRITE)
file.write(script)
file.close()
// execute
intent = makeIntent(...)
startActivity(intent)
```

Good luck!